# How do you set puback and pubrel in python mqtt (paho library)?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

How do you generate packets for PUBACK and PUBREL and most importantly, how do you know what the packetId of the received message is?

I would like to be able to handle the logic for PUBREL and PUBACKs myself. The code below should give a hint of what I'm trying to do.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue  
# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from 
the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("/test")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
def my_function(id):
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id="id", clean_session=False,userdata=None, protocol=MQTTv311)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

    client.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)
    msgs = [{'topic':"/test", 'payload':"ClientId: " +id }, 'QoS': 2, 'retain': False),
    {'topic':"/test", 'payload':"ClientId: " +id }, 'QoS': 2, 'retain': False),
    {'topic':"/test", 'payload':"ClientId: " +id }, 'QoS': 2, 'retain': False)]
    publish.multiple(msgs, hostname="127.0.0.1", port=1883,client_id=id, keepalive=60,will=None, auth=None, tls=None, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
    # Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
    # handles reconnecting.
    # Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
    # manual interface.
    client.loop_forever()
for i in range(0,10):
    p = Process(target=my_function, args=(str(i))
```

Comment: Why do you want to take over these actions from the paho library, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @hardillb I just want to code my own logic for client sessions etc. i.e. I want to be able to store the packet id when the connection is lost and server side I want to test whether the generated packet id is relevant to all subscribed clients or is just relevant to the client that is receiving the on_flight messages. For exemple if there is 100 clients subscribed to a channel I want to know if the packetid is going to increment for messages sent independantly of the actual client or if it increments in a per client fashion. The documentation is not too clear about that.

Comment: Then I suggest you look at the paho code directly, I'm not aware of any hooks to replace these functions on the fly.

Comment: Do u know the answer to the second question though ? It could save me some time @hardillb

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while working on exploiting a possible MQTT vulnerability. To my knowledge Paho doesn't have any modules to handle more low-level packets, for that you could use [Scapy's MQTT module](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/contrib/mqtt.py).

Scapy is a module in Python that allows you to handle packets of a variety of protocols, here's how to send an MQTT CONNECT using scapy:

```py
from scapy.contrib.mqtt import MQTTConnect
from scapy.all import send, IP, TCP

mqtt_broker_ip = '192.168.0.1'
mqtt_broker_port = 1883

ip_pkt = IP(dst=mqtt_broker_ip)
tcp_pkt = TCP(dport=mqtt_broker_port)
mqtt_pkt = MQTTConnect(clientId='my_client_id')

# use slashes (/) to stack protocols 
final_pkt = ip_pkt/tcp_pkt/mqtt_pkt

send(mqtt_pkt)
```